# Using locally saved SetFit model

Tags: nlp, prediction, huggingface-transformers, few-shot-learning

I saved SetFit model locally, now I want to use it in order to make predictions (for model deployment), I tried the following code:

```
from setfit import SetFitModel
model = SetFitModel.from_pretrained("CyberBullying/cyberbullying-classification-setfit-model-v1")
preds = model(["i loved the spiderman movie!", "Another Idiot ...is India really Full of them. It's has nothing to do with BJP / CONgress or Hindu-Muslim, it's about Rich/Poor. You all are so uneducated , but literate ."])
print('========================Predictions========================')
print(preds)
```

but it appears the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "F:\Chahinez RSI\prediction.py", line 3, in 
> model = SetFitModel.from_pretrained("CyberBullying/cyberbullying-classification-setfit-model-v1")
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils_validators.py", line 118, in _inner_fn
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\hub_mixin.py", line 159, in from_pretrained
> return cls._from_pretrained(
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setfit\modeling.py", line 549, in _from_pretrained
> model_head = joblib.load(model_head_file)
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 587, in load
> obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 506, in _unpickle
> obj = unpickler.load()
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pickle.py", line 1213, in load
> dispatchkey[0]
> KeyError: 0

Answer (score 0):

you may have already figured this out (old post) but you should use:

```
preds = model.predict(['sentence1','sentence2'])
print(preds)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).